# Downloading mp3 files directly

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I've been using xamarin for a while and the current project I'm working on will require some mp3 files to be downloaded.

I saw tutorials for downloading a file and downloading an image, but they didn't lead me anywhere and are for iOS.

Given a url `www.xyz.com/music.mp3`, how do I download the mp3 file and save it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way is to use WebClient and if on the UI thread then call method DownloadFileTaskAsync:

```
        button.Click += async delegate
        {
            var destination = Path.Combine(
                System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                    "music.mp3");

            await new WebClient().DownloadFileTaskAsync(
                new Uri("http://www.xyz.com/music.mp3"),
                destination);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

### Xamarin.iOS Docs converted to download bytes

The [Xamarin.iOS docs `WebClient` sample for downloading a file](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_a_file/) should work just fine after you tweak from downloading a string to downloading bytes (note `DownloadDataAsync` and `DownloadDataCompleted` vs `String` sibling functions).

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) => {
    var text = e.Result; // get the downloaded text
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string localFilename = "downloaded.mp3";
    string localPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename);
    File.WriteAllText (localpath, text); // writes to local storage   
};
var url = new Uri("http://url.to.some/file.mp3"); // give this an actual URI to an MP3
webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);
```

### Using HttpClient

If you want to use the newer `HttpClient` library. Add a reference to `System.Net.Http` to your Xamarin.Android project and give something like this a shot.

```
var url = new Uri("http://url.to.some/file.mp3");
var httpClient = new HttpClient ();
httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url).ContinueWith(data => {
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string localFilename = "downloaded.mp3";
    string localPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename);
    File.WriteAllBytes (localPath, data.Result);
});
```